# beautifulsoup find_all bug?

Tags: beautifulsoup, findall

Nowadays I am using beautiful soup to parse the html page. But sometimes the result I got by find_all is less than the number in pages. For example, this page http://www.totallyfreestuff.com/index.asp?m=0&sb=1&p=5 has 18 headline span. But when i use the following codes, it just got two! Can anybody tell me why. Thank you in advance!

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
hrefDivList = soup.find_all("span", class_ = "headline")
#print hrefDivList
print len(hrefDivList)
```

Comment: how did you get the `page`? your code prints 18 in my case.

Comment: I get the page using urllib, and I printed the page out. it did has 18 headline span in the page. But my codes just got two. Can you share your codes to me?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using different parser for Beautifulsoup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "<your url>"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
hrefDivList = soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class": "headline"})
print len(hrefDivList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try CSS Selectors to make your life easier

```
hrefDivList = soup.select("span.headline")
#print hrefDivList
print len(hrefDivList)
```

Or you can directly iterate over every Span text

```
for every_span in soup.select("span.headline"):
    print(every_span.text)
```