# Why isn't beautifulsoup's find_all not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have decided to view a website's source code, and chose a class, which is "expanded". I wanted to print out all of its contents, with this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-a-bot-using-Python")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print soup.find_all(class_='expanded')
```

but it simply prints out:

> []

Please help me detect what's wrong.

I already saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447522/beautifulsoup-find-all-bug) and tried following what the answer said but it did not help me since this error appears in the terminal:

> bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: When I view source of that webpage and look for that class you mentioned I get no results. How did you find the class? Did you see it in the inspector, not the source like you said?

Comment: @csmckelvey alright, I changed it. Please see the edited version of my post, and also, that "expanded" class is in line 6 of the view-source

Comment: I see lots of classes that contain the word "expanded" (`__w2_b6iUSHv_expanded_content`, `ui_qtext_expanded`, etc...) but there is no class named only "expanded".

Comment: @csmckelvey view-source:https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-a-bot-using-Python line 6, 5th word

Comment: Maybe we are on different browsers and the server gives different responses for them because I don't have it there. Since I cannot reproduce I will have to move on. Here's is line 6 of view source for me `});});</script><script type="text/javascript">document.title="How to write a bot using Python - Quora";</script><script type='text/javascript'>require.whenReady("shared/main-loaded", function() {`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [beautifulsoup find\_all bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447522/beautifulsoup-find-all-bug)

Comment: The very class `expanded` indeed present in the page source. Check out [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4jyxfbgemntu3j/Untitled.jpg?dl=0).

Comment: @csmckelvey https://imgur.com/OdZpEvr

Answer (score 1):

When searching for a class value, you should pass it in like this:

```
soup.find_all(attrs={"class":"expanded"})
```

That being said, I don't see anything in the source code of that site with a class called "expanded". The closest thing I could find was class='ui_qtext_expanded'. If that is what you are trying to find, you need to include the whole string.

```
soup.find_all(attrs={"class":"ui_qtext_expanded"})
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid but where do you view the source code? I view it using view-source, and it's in line 6, 5th word

Comment: That's strange. I am using view source, and  I don't see it. Can you copy/paste the exact line?

Comment: What do you get from calling soup.prettify()? Look for your class tag in there. If you don't see it, then your request call is pulling something different from what you are seeing with view source.