# Why is the html in view-source different from what I see in the terminal when I call prettify()?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have decided to view a website's source code, and chose a class, which is "expanded" ([I found it using view-source](https://imgur.com/OdZpEvr), prettify() shows different code). I wanted to print out all of its contents, with this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-a-bot-using-Python")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print soup.find_all(class_='expanded')
```

but it simply prints out:

> []

Please help me detect what's wrong.

I already saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447522/beautifulsoup-find-all-bug) and tried following what the answer said but it did not help me since this error appears in the terminal:

> bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: Use `page.text` instead of `page.content`

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the site in question and the only class similar was actually named `ui_qtext_expanded`

When you use `findAll` / `find_all` you have to iterate over it to return each item as it is a list of items using `.text`.. That is if you want the text and not the actual HTML..

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-a-bot-using-Python")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
res = soup.find_all(class_='ui_qtext_expanded')
for i in res:
    print i.text
```

The beginning of the output from your link is

`A combination of mechanize, Requests and BeautifulSoup works pretty good for the basic stuff.Learn about mechanize here.Mechanize is sufficient for basic form filling, form submission and that sort of stuff, but for real browser emulation (like dealing with Javascript rendered HTML) you should look into selenium.`

Comment: so you're saying that view-source is unreliable when I want to do something with the actual information from the website, like ticking boxes for example? I need to print to the terminal the entire html just to view it?